# Find $\int_1^\infty \frac{\{x\}}{x(x+1)}dx,$ where $\{x\}$ means $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

Question: Find $\int_1^\infty \frac{\{x\}}{x(x+1)}dx,$ where $\{x\}$ means $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.

I have attempted to split this into two integrals, namely
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{x(x+1)}dx - \int_1^\infty \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x(x+1)}dx,$$ however did not get anywhere. I have also considered that the average value of $\{x\}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ (I think).

With mostly just instincts and jotting down a few numbers, I obtained an answer of $\ln{\sqrt{2}}$, which seems reasonable since Desmos approximated the answer (when the upper limit is large) as 0.30…
I am only 17 so try to keep notation at my level, though this shouldn't really involve anything too complicated.

Answer (score 18):

[Telescopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) approach: note that for $R>2$,
\begin{align}
\int_1^R \frac{\{x\}}{x(x+1)}\,dx
&=\int_1^R \left(\frac{\{x\}}{x}-\frac{\{x\}}{x+1}\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_1^R \frac{\{x\}}{x}\,dx-\int_1^R \frac{\{x+1\}}{x+1}\,dx
\qquad(\{x+1\}=\{x\})\\
&=\int_1^R \frac{\{x\}}{x}\,dx-\int_2^{R+1} \frac{\{x\}}{x}\,dx\\
&=\int_1^2 \frac{\{x\}}{x}\,dx-\int_R^{R+1} \frac{\{x\}}{x}\,dx\\
&=\int_1^2 \frac{x-1}{x}\,dx-\int_R^{R+1} \frac{\{x\}}{x}\,dx.
\end{align}
What happens as $R\to +\infty$?

Show that, in the last line, the first integral is equal to $1-\ln(2)\approx 0.30685$, whereas the second one goes to zero.

Answer (score 11):

\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty \frac{\{x\}}{x(x+1)}dx
=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_k^{k+1}\frac{x-k}{x(x+1)} \overset{y=x-k}{dx}\\
=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_0^{1}\frac{y}{(y+k)(y+k+1)}dy\\
=& \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k+1)\ln\frac {k+2}{k+1}-k\ln\frac{k+1}k\\
=& \ \lim_{k\to \infty} (k+1)\ln\frac {k+2}{k+1}- \ln2
= 1-\ln2
\end{align}